# Algorithm to find the spacing of unique points on the perimeter of a Christmas tree

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

I thought of an algorithm and would like to put it in preferably C++, if not, then in Python.  It requires the user input three variables, the diameter of the circle, the number of unique points they want on the perimeter of that circle, and how much of that circle they want viewed. Eventually I'd like to make it more complex and incorporate the decreasing width as we travel upwards as all Christmas trees are multi-layered (though I'd start at the top and go down as there are less paths of travel at the top than bottom) but that requires more thought than I can give at the moment. An example and the formula are below.

*Example:*

If I have a Christmas tree that is 8 ft in diameter, there are 4 uniquely colored ornaments to hang, and only 2/3 of the tree is showing (since it is in the corner of the house), what is the equal length between each ornament?

The initial spacing S would be 4.2 ft

S1 = 1.05 ft

S2 = .2 ft

```
**Variable Explanation                                          User Input**

Pi  The number Pi                                                           N
D   Diameter                                                                Y
C   Number of colors (or number of unique points you want on the circle)    Y
X   0-1; how much of the tree or circle will be viewed (two decimals)       Y
```

**Formula**

S= (X*pi*D)/C

```
S1  S/C 
S2  S1/C
```

**Generalized Formula**

```
SN  SN-1/C
```

**Question**: What is the code to loop the algorithm?

It seems the best way to find the answer is to have the user input X, D, and C which will equal S.  But how do you write in S1=S/C, S2=S1/C, and so on?

Comment: So... what's the question? I can't find a single question-mark in the entire "question".

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the diameter `d`, radius `r = d / 2`, the proportion of the visible part `p` and the number of ornaments `n`. E.g. `p = 0.5` means half of the tree is visible.

First we need the length of the arc that is actually visible:

```
l = PI * d * p
```

Now we need to calculate the space between each ornament:

```
s = l / (n - 1)
```

The first ornament will be placed at 0, the last one at l and the rest in between.

Now for the second part:
Calculating this over the entire tree:
Let's assume you want to place the ornaments with a distance of `h` in terms of hight and the entire tree-hight is `H`:

The length of the arc on which the ornaments are placed can be calculated as

```
d(h) = (d / H) * h
```

E.g. at height 3 with `H = 6` and `d = 2`, we will get `d(3) = 1`.

Putting this together, we get the function from height to distance between ornaments as:

```
s(h) = PI * (d / H) * h * p / (n - 1)
```

Just loop over the heights at which you want to place the ornaments and you're done.